# Do Boost Geometry nearest queries always sort results ordered by smallest distance first?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have made a few simple Cartesian Point to Point tests:

```
rtree.qbegin(bgi::nearest(Point(4, 4), 2))
```

and they were sorted in Boost 1.61.

Now I'd like a documentation or source quote to confirm it.

If not, I will just sort the query output myself afterwards.

Comment: I'm going to be impolite and plink @BarendGehrels and @ AdamWulkiewicz - I think the question is likely simple to answer for some of you. Perhaps information could be added to the documentation :) Cheers

Comment: There is information about it in the docs regarding the iterative query (cited below in the answer) but sure I may put there something regarding non-iterative one.

Answer (score 5):

> [Note] In the case of iterative k-NN queries it is guaranteed to iterate over the closest Values first.

For K Nearest Neighbours boost::geometry guarantees to iterate over closest values first.

[Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html#geometry.spatial_indexes.queries.iterative_queries)

Comment: Yes, in case of iterative queries it's guaranteed to get the closest values first. In case of the non-iterative query the values may be not sorted.